# My Composite nodes doesn't effect the final render (It's connected to composite)

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, transparency

[image: Composite view]

[image: Exported render view]

As you can see the exported render doesn't have the bloom (the bg is transparent, it's not white. I imported it to premiere with a black bg and there is no bloom).

Also the Composite node is connected.

Comment: Hi :). Is it a PNG format by any chance? Because PNG doesn't support both emissive and transparent pixels — so you lose the glow.

Comment: yes, it's png . Are there other formats that support it?

Comment: Hey :). There are detailed answers on this site regarding this problem and what to do ;). I'll try to get back later and link some.